# Websphere OSGi: Declarative Services

Tags: websphere, osgi

I am trying to get a simple osgi bundle in a OSGi Enterprise Application on WebSphere 8. During the publishing process the following error occurs:

---

```
*Application asset import failed.
```

CWSAL0015E: Cannot resolve EBA file. Exception: org.apache.aries.application.management.ResolverException: The system cannot provision the EBA IbisOSGi because the following problems in the dependency chain were detected: 
The package dependency org.osgi.service.component with the version greater than or equal to 1.1.0 required by bundle [...]*

---

The required package is available in the plugins/osgiapplications/[...]/aries folder of the WebSphere Server. The package is declared in the manifest.mf file of a bundle:
[...]
`Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.5.0",
 org.osgi.service.component;version="1.1.0"`
[...]
Has anybody any suggestions?

Comment: Solution: Websphere 8.0 does not support declarative services with its all features...

Answer (score 0):

Your options are to use [Blueprint](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/os-osgiblueprint/index.html%20Blueprint), or to move up to WebSphere 8.5.5 and the [Liberty profile](http://www.wasdev.net). 8.5.5 allows you to [extend the runtime with user features](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v9/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_declare_services_ds.html) which can use declarative services.